# Getting error when trying to delete a file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, itext

I have a an html data in a literal and i make a pdf file say `scan.pdf` from that html using `iTextsharp` .But when i try to delete the created pdf file using File.Delete() method,it shows an error like

D:\Hosting\filepath\scan.pdf' because it is being used by another process

How can i solve it?

this is the code for creating pdf file from html and send it to some mailid as attachment

```
   string MailFormat = searchDt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
            EmalBody.Append(MailFormat);
            EmalBody.Replace("[Date]", DateTime.Today.ToString());
            string emailbody = EmalBody.ToString();
            message.Body = EmalBody.ToString();
            ***HTMLToPdf(emailbody, "scan.pdf");***
            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
            attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(Server.MapPath("scan.pdf"));
            message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Subject = "";
            smtpClient.Send(message);
            File.Delete("D://filepath//scan.pdf");

   public void HTMLToPdf(string HTML, string FilePath)
   {
   Document document = new Document();
   PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("D:\\filepath\\scan.pdf",FileMode.Create));
    document.Open();

    iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet styles = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
    iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);
    hw.Parse(new StringReader(HTML));
    document.Close();
    }
```

Comment: would really need to see the code, but it looks like you are accessing this file twice, but not disposing of the objects trying to use the file. e.g. reading it, and then deleting it while the reader is still open

Comment: Are you reading the file into memory beforehand? Is it properly disposed?

Comment: you have to release any other object holding the file or have to kill process that is using your pf, please share the code

Comment: You must freeing memory and releasing file handles before you call the `File.Delete()`.

Comment: i tried gc.collect before delete the file,but no use.Showing same error.How can i dispose the file object?

Comment: No need to downvote this one, you could just ask for a code snippet.

Comment: @Anilkumar `GC.Collect` has nothing to do with this. This method traverses the managed heap and reclaims the memory from objects that have no roots.

Comment: then how can i relase the file handles before calling `file.Delete()`

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not disposing resources after you produce the PDF file. Usually it's done by calling "Close" and/or "Dispose" methods on the corresponding objects.

If the object implements `IDisposable`, you can just use the `using` construct. This way resources will be freed once the execution passes the `using` block (this also guarantees that the resources are freed even if there's an exception inside the `using` block).

Answer (score 1):

After saving the file in Textsharp you still have the file in use, because you haven't `cleaned` all handles to the file. Your writer is probably not within a using block, see which other classes should be disposed by checking if they are disposable. If you find them, make sure you dispose them, so all handles will be released.

some sample code:

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(temp_filename, FileMode.Create))
{
    iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
    ...
}

//    Do the delete after using block
```

The delete must be outside your using block. If you still have the error check the code where you are using the file (send it to the client etc).

Answer (score 1):

actually i forgot to free the mail attachment object,and thats why i got the error.When i put this code `attachment.Dispose();` the error got cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this Textsharp library before but I would guess you can solve this by just either creating the file in a using block:

```
using(PdfWriter MyWriter=PdfWriter.GetInstance(Document,Stream))
{
...
}
```

or by simply calling .dispose() on it:

```
MyWriter.Dispose()
```

If you could show your code it would help to debug the exact location of your problem.

Comment: @Anilkumar and where is your delete call in reference to this?

Comment: i didnt write,can u guide me please?

Comment: @Anilkumar "But when i try to delete the created pdf file using File.Delete()" where is that?

Comment: after `smtpClient.Send(message)`

Comment: try changing your PdfWriter to use a using block as my answer says